# Extract character from a string bug

Tags: c, string, file, scanf

I read in a temp variable from a file, this is one word, e.g. "and", however, when I extract the first character, e.g. temp[1], the program crashes when running, I have tried break points, and it is on this line.

This is what happens when I run the code: http://prntscr.com/2vzkmp

These are the words when I don't try to extract a letter: http://prntscr.com/2vzktn

This is the error when I use breakpoints: http://prntscr.com/2vzlr3

This is the line that is messing up: " printf("\n%s \n",temp[0]);"

Here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char **dictmat;
    char temp[100];
    int i = 0, comp, file, found = 0, j = 0, foundmiss = 0;

    FILE* input;

    dictmat = ReadDict();


    /*opens the text file*/
    input = fopen("y:\\textfile.txt", "r");

    /*checks if we can open the file, otherwise output error message*/
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open textfile.txt for reading \n");
    }
    else
    {
        /*allocates the memory location to the rows using a for loop*/

        do
        {
            /*temp_line is now the contents of the line in the file*/
            file = fscanf(input, "%s", temp);
            if (file != EOF)
            {

                lowercase_remove_punct(temp, temp);
                for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    comp = strcmp(temp, dictmat[i]);
                    if (comp == 0)
                    {
                        /*it has found the word in the dictionary*/
                        found = 1;

                    }

                }

                /*it has not found a word in the dictionay, so the word must be misspelt*/
                if (found == 0 && (strcmp(temp, "") !=0))
                {

                    /*temp is the variable that is misspelt*/
                    printf("\n%s \n",temp[0]);

                    /*checks for a difference of one letter*/
                    //one_let(temp);
                }
                found = 0;
                foundmiss = 0;


            }

        } while (file != EOF);

        /*closes the file*/
        fclose(input);


    }


    free_matrix(dictmat);


    return 0;


}
```

Comment: why not use `%c` for print character?

Comment: That worked, but why did it not work wit %s?

Comment: @Hamoudy: `temp[0]` is a `char`. That's 8 bits on most machines, representing the numerical representation of a character of the current encoding. `%s` expects a `char *`, which is 32 or 64 bits on most machines, representing the *address* of the first character of a (zero-terminated) string (`char[]`). Go figure what happens when you take the first 4 or 8 characters from your string and interpret the numerical representation of characters as an address...

Comment: if i was going to do as comparision for this charchter, how would i do it? e.g. strcmp(temp[0], word[0])?

Comment: @Hamoudy: `temp[0] == word[0]` / `temp[0] != word[0]`.

Comment: you'd have to provide the address, since %s expects a char* so like `&temp[0]` you pass instead `temp[0]`.

Comment: @JKB: Wouldn't it be *much* simpler, let alone semantically more correct, to just pass `temp` instead of `&temp[0]`?

Comment: @DevSolar but what if `temp[1]..temp[2]..so on`. this is not OP require but it is the case.

Comment: @JKB: I'm not sure what you are talking about. As far as `printf()` and its `%s` are concerned, `&temp[0]` and `temp` are the same thing *syntactically*. But *semantically* you're passing a pointer to char array (`temp`), not the address of a single character (`&temp[0]`). For this, and for the simpler syntax, I'd prefer (and recommend) `temp`.

Answer (score 2):

When printing a character, use `%c`, not `%s`.
There is a fundamental difference between the two. The latter is for strings.

When printf encounters a `%c` it inserts one byte in ASCII format into the output stream from the variable specified.

When it sees a `%s` it will interpret the variable as a character pointer, and start copying bytes in ASCII format from the address specified in the variable, until it encounters a byte that contains zero.

Answer (score 1):

print char - not string:

```
printf("\n%c \n",temp[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked,  but why did it not work with %s?

Comment: @ziollek - Even though he uses %s is should print rite? The compiler should take the base address and has to print the string since %s used

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now

Comment: @ziollek - so if we type cast to (char *)temp[0] it should work rite?

Comment: no. you can provide to printf pointer to first letter &temp[0] (&temp[0] is the same pointer as temp), but in this case it prints whole string (not just first letter)

Answer (score 1):

temp[0] is a charater. Thus if you are using

```
printf("\n%s \n",temp[0]);
```

it will print the string from `address i.e. temp[0]`. May be this location is not accessible, So it is crashing.

This change it to

```
printf("\n%c \n",temp[0]);
```

Comment: `printf("\n%s \n", temp[0])` will use `temp[0]` as an address.

Comment: @JKB that also point to base address and that is particulary allocated for temp array. So if access that location valid content you will get. But if you try to access location temp[0], consider it as 68. Will it be valid to access content from 68?

Comment: if i was going to do as comparision for this charchter, how would i do it? e.g. strcmp(temp[0], word[0])?

Comment: @Hamoudy temp[0] will be a char so you can use temp[0]==word[0]. If you want to compare whole string then use strcmp(temp,word)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using %s as modifier, use %c